# Create a unique array combining more than one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code in PHP

```
foreach ($events as $event)
{
    $event = $event->organiser;
    var_dump($event);
}
```

Then i am getting output like for $event

```
array
 0 => string '40138' (length=5)
 1 => string '40137' (length=5)
array
 0 => string '40140' (length=5)
 1 => string '40138' (length=5)
```

Next i am creating a loop to get values as per the above ID (40137,40138) in to one array, here i want to create a unique array. How to do that ?

So as per the unique ID i can create the following UI

```
foreach ($events as $event)
{
if(!empty($event->organiser)){
        if(is_array($event->organiser)){
        foreach ($event->organiser as $organiser){
            $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
            $name = $mentors_entities->title;

            $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
            $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";  
        }
        }else{
            $organiser = $event->organiser;
            $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
            $name = $mentors_entities->title;

            $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
            $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";
        }
    }
}
```

So how to get the unique array combining of multiple array ?

Comment: Use [array_filter](http://ir2.php.net/array_filter) function.

Comment: I tried that but its didn't worked for me..i tried like           $event = $event->organiser;
  $counts = array_filter($event, create_function('$x', 'return $x > 1;'));
  var_dump($counts);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$organisers = array_reduce($events, function($ids, $el){ //lets collect all the ids in one array
    if(is_array($el->organiser)){
        $ids = array_merge($ids, $el->organiser);
    }else{
        $ids[] = $el->organiser;
    }
    return $ids;
}, array()); 
$orgsUnique = array_unique($organisers); //leave only uniqie ids

foreach ($orgsUnique as $organiser)
{
    //do what you need...
    $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
    $name = $mentors_entities->title;

    $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
    $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";
}
```

For php under 5.3 (when lamba-functions weren't supported):

```
function reduceFunc($ids, $el){ 
    if(is_array($el->organiser)){
        $ids = array_merge($ids, $el->organiser);
    }else{
        $ids[] = $el->organiser;
    }
    return $ids;
}

$organisers = array_reduce($events, 'reduceFunc', array()); //lets collect all the ids in one array
$orgsUnique = array_unique($organisers); //leave only uniqie ids

foreach ($orgsUnique as $organiser)
{
    //do what you need...
    $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
    $name = $mentors_entities->title;

    $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
    $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";
}
```

Comment: Its showing error. Its saying unexpected function at $organisers = array_reduce($events, function($ids, $el){.  what to do ? is it supported by PHP 5.3 version

Comment: looks like you have old php. Try the 2nd solution.

Comment: Thanks dude its working perfectly. Thanks for ur tym & effort

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you looking for, but the below code makes sure your ID is not printed twice:

```
$rec_values = array(); // will store the array values
if(!empty($event->organiser)){
        if(is_array($event->organiser)){ 
        foreach ($event->organiser as $organiser){
            //checks if ID has been entered before
            //if not, display it
            if(!in_array($organiser,$rec_values)){
            $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
            $name = $mentors_entities->title;

            $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
            $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";  
            $rec_values[] =$organiser; //record the ID 
            }
        }
        }else{
            //same for the else part
            if(!in_array($organiser,$rec_values)){
            $organiser = $event->organiser;
            $mentors_entities = get_entity($organiser);
            $name = $mentors_entities->title;

            $img = $vars['url'].'mod/mentor/icon.php?mentorguid='.$organiser;
            $body .= "<div class='event_mntdes'><div class='event_mntimg'><img src=".$img.'&size=large'."></div><div class='event_mntcontent'><b>".$name."</b><br/>".elgg_get_excerpt($mentors_entities->mentorshrt,'150')."</div></div>";
            $rec_values[] =$organiser; //record the ID
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RIADev If I'm correct, your array has repeating IDs and you want to display only unique ones, right?

Comment: In the above code, the array `$rec_values` will have all the unique values. What problem are you facing with the code? Maybe you should do a `print_r($organiser);` inside the `foreach` and add what it prints to your question.

Comment: Its printing "4013740138" only. Its missing the 40140

Comment: Since I just saw your edited post of the first `foreach` loop, add the `$rec_values = array();` before the first `foreach` and try.